# Using custom dialect function in hibernate @Formula

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hsqldb

I defined my custom dialect for HSQLDB:

```
public class CustomHSQLDialect extends HSQLDialect {

    public CustomHSQLDialect () {
        super();
        registerFunction("datediffsec", new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE, "cast((?1 - ?2) AS INTERVAL SECOND)"));
    }
}
```

I defined configuration:

```
hibernate.dialect=custom.dialect.CustomHSQLDialect
```

Then I'm trying to use it in @Formula:

```
@Formula("case status when 'ACTIVE' then datediffsec(now(), creationDateTime) when 'CLEARED' then datediffsec(clearedDateTime, creationDateTime) end")
```

But I catch exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or
>   object not found: DATEDIFFSEC

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can create this function as an SQL expression in Hibernate.

But supposing you could, this expression is wrong as far as HSQLDB is concerned.

A correct expression would be like:

```
 (?1 - ?2) INTERVAL SECOND
```

Also note there is already a TIMESTAMPDIFF function in HSQLDB which allows you to specify seconds as the unit.

Comment: (?1 - ?2) SECOND works for me (as expression in my post), but trouble is different. Hibernate parser misses registered custom function